# How can I make a drag handle drag correctly in Framer Motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I wanted to replicate this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMGnYRJuJog) that shows how to create a drag handle in Framer X. Using `framer-motion`, I thought it worked but I am getting extra space on dragging that shouldn't occur. It may be something with `display: flex` but I'm not entirely sure, whether I'm doing something incorrectly or whether this is a bug in `framer-motion.`

**CodeSandbox reproduction**

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-cerf-kh9o5

**Steps to reproduce**

Create two panels and a drag handle, and make the handle add width to one panel and subtract from another.

**Expected behavior**

The handle should drag and not have extra space. It should also follow the mouse which it is not doing.

**Video reproduction**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKAgM.gif

**Environment details**

Windows 10, Chrome

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to first control the container's `y` position using a motion value, then use an `onPan` event (on the handle) to set that motion value's value.

```
function Example() {
  const containerY = useMotionValue(0)

  return (
    <motion.div style={{ y: containerY }}>
      <motion.div onPan={(e, info) => containerY.set(info.offset.y)}>
        Drag Me
      </motion.div>
      <div>Can't drag me</div>
    </motion.div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you give a CodeSandbox example of the tutorial I linked? I see your example works for a basic drag example but doesn't work for a drag handle like in the tutorial. I've modified the CodeSandbox I linked above to use onPan but it still seems to not behave correctly. Thanks.

Comment: So I was able to solve the issue, at least with a one-sided panel (https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-smoke-fjleg). Sorry, I just didn't read your answer carefully enough, my bad (I put the style on the DragHandle which shouldn't be there). I am interested to know why onPan works while onDrag creates the extra spacing. It seems like I'd have to reimplement elasticity/momentum, dragConstraints and drag="xy" through the onPan gesture rather than using the onDrag one due to this. Is there another way to accomplish this with just onDrag?